# LineHeight taking extra space for multiline text in android compose Text

Tags: android, kotlin, text, android-jetpack-compose

I am using Compose Text component and I have observed that when the text component is in multiline it is taking extra height as shown in below screenshoot.[image]

Here is my code of above screenshoot.

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier,
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
) {
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(
                color = Color.Magenta
            ),
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        text = "Hello World!"
    )

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp))

    Text(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(
                color = Color.Magenta
            ),
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        text = "Hello World!\nAnil Adhikary",
        lineHeight = 24.sp
    )
}
```

Comment: If the first Text is "X" height for one line and the second one is "2X" for two lines, what do you mean by extra height?

Answer (score 0):

It's called "Font padding".
You can disable it like that:

```
    Text(
        text = "Your Text",
        style = TextStyle(
            platformStyle = PlatformTextStyle(
                includeFontPadding = false
            )
        )
    )
```

By the way it's a great article which explanates concept of "Font padding"

[Fixing Font Padding in Compose Text](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/fixing-font-padding-in-compose-text-768cd232425b)

Comment: IDEA complains with: `None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
<init>(PlatformSpanStyle?, PlatformParagraphStyle?) defined in androidx.compose.ui.text.PlatformTextStyle
<init>(TextDecorationLineStyle?) defined in androidx.compose.ui.text.PlatformTextStyle`

Comment: Sorry. Apparently ui-text-desktop does not have the bland PlatformTextStyle() constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If you are coming from **Compose Multiplatform**, you won't have the `PlatformTextStyle()` constructor where you can give the `includeFontPadding` option. See this discussion: https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/issues/2477

You can find recommendations on how to deal with line height in the 1.6.0 release notes: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/kotlin-multiplatform-dev/whats-new-compose-1-6-0.html#breaking-changes

Example:

```
    Text(
        text = "loong text",
        style = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(
            fontSize = 12.sp,
            lineHeight = 0.sp,
            lineHeightStyle = LineHeightStyle(
                alignment = LineHeightStyle.Alignment.Center,
                trim = LineHeightStyle.Trim.Both // Adjust this to change trimming behavior
            )
        ),
         ...
```